# Looking for political maps (administrative division)

Tags: web-mapping, administrative-boundaries

I'm looking for an interactive map that shows ONLY administrative divisions of a country. I need to personalize it so when the user clicks a region, the map shows some information about it. If it comes in colors and animations, it would be better. Is there a way I can achieve this? I've seen around and I found very good maps but maybe they show additional geographic information that is really good but might not be relevant for my web application (PHP).
One more thing: I'm avoiding the use of Flash and Java Applets.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.studentsoftheworld.info/menu_infopays.html like this?

Comment: Good approach, but I need the internal division of a country.

Comment: Would you be prepared to to build your own database for internal divisions?

Comment: I would, if there was no other way.

Comment: have a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative - though some countries are limited but you download the data using the API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind creating your own application you could make use of the natural earth data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). The quality is excellent and breaks down to state-/province-level. Additionally, the data has a lot of attribute information.

Comment: Do you know if this is different from the Global Admin Boundaries? http://www.gadm.org/

Answer (score 2):

The US Department of State’s Humanitarian Information Unit recently released a new data set, the Large Scale International Boundaries. Available at https://hiu.state.gov/data/data.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can you just load the world data and then use this information to create a list of keywords from the attribute table ?

http://www.aubreyrhea.net/gis/index.php/2010/03/creating-a-list-of-keywords-from-the-attribute-table/

See if this is what you were looking for ?

Robert

Answer (score 0):

For the UK all administrative boundaries are available for free from [Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html).